# Qual a importância do PWA (Progressive Web App) atualmente?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

Acompanho esses pwas a um bom tempo e sempre procuro ter o PWA de qualquer projeto meu pois é uma das exigências do Google Audits.

Porém, **gostaria de entender qual é a real importância dele no cenário atual**.

Temos os webapps funcionando apenas em android e desktop. **Por algum motivo o iOS não funciona ainda a questão de sugerir o download do webapp**. A ideia é criar uma alternativa ao PlayStore/AppleStore? Vale a pena investir além de aplicativos, webapps também? É uma preocupação a mais que gostaria de saber se vale a pena continuar investindo esforço.

Comment: O [Chrome 73](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ksWDVurubwE) adicionou suporte ao OSX para PWA. Todos OS suportam desktop suportam PWA's,

Comment: Sim, eu não expressei de forma correta. Na verdade, no iOS ele não sugere ainda o download do webapp como é feito no android e no osx